# Razor MVC get select option ID for SQL statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to submit a simple form with razor, needing the

```
<select>
   <option id=""> //this is what i neeed to perform an insert >
   </option>
</select>
```

my razor syntax is as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.aPracticar.Value, actividades , "Seleccione la actividad" ,new { @class="form-control" })
```

The value itself will not do since i neeed to perform sql joins and i dont know how to obtain that id via razor. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

EDIT:

Sory for the late update. Found a relatively simple workaround since i had to utilize the ids instead of the values in the select list for a Javascript function. I am fully aware that this may not a correct usage of razor but proved effective in contrast to rewriting an entire model/view/controller

```
    <div class="editor-label">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.aPracticar.Value, "Actividad")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <select class="form-control" id="aPracticar_Value" >                
            <option value="">Seleccione la actividad...</option>
             @foreach (var actividad in actividades)
             {  
                <option id="@actividad.idDeporte" value="@actividad.Value">
                          @actividad.Text</option>

         }                                   
    </select>
     @Html.HiddenFor(u => u.aPracticar.idDeporte)
     <br />
 </div>
```

However, I'm marking one of the answers below as correct since it's an example of the intended usage of Razor. Thanks again everyone for the useful comments.

Comment: `<option>` elements need a `value` attribute (not an `id`) and a `<select>` posts back the value of the `selected` option (or the text if no `value` attribute is present). What is `actividades` in your `DropDownListFor()` method? - The `DropDownListFor()` method will do all this correctly is you provide it the correct data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert drop down list options through `DropDownList` helper, build a `List<SelectListItem>` or create `SelectList` constructor from predefined model:

```
// assume Model.Selecciones is an IEnumerable option list
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.aPracticar, "actividades", new SelectList(Model.Selecciones), new { @class="form-control" })

// assume Model.ListaSelecciones is a SelectListItem option list
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.aPracticar, "actividades", Model.ListaSelecciones, new { @class="form-control" })
```

Both of them will roughly translated to HTML as this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="aPracticar">
    <option value="Valor">Texto</option>
    <!-- other option values -->
</select>
```

If you want to build a list of SelectListItem:

```
Model.ListaSelecciones = new List<SelectListItem>();

lista.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Texto", Value = "Valor" } // example for adding option item to drop down list
```

However if you tend to directly bind select list items to view, provide text-value pair on your model first.

The selected value from drop-down list will automatically insert into `model.aPracticar` property on form submitting.

**Addendum**: DropDownList generated option tag doesn't contain "id" attribute by default. You need to make custom HTML helper with extended option tag attribute similar to this:

```
public class ExtendedSelectListItem : SelectListItem
{
    public Object htmlAttributes { get; set; }
}

public class CustomHtmlHelper
{
    // taken from stackoverflow.com/a/7772354: requires by HTML helper to get model state
    public static Object GetModelStateValue(HtmlHelper helper, String key, Type destinationType)
    {
        ModelState state;
        if (helper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(key, out state))
        {
            if (state.Value != null)
            {
                return state.Value.ConvertTo(destinationType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // this part inspired from stackoverflow.com/a/7537628
    public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListForId<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<ExtendedSelectListItem> selectList, String optionLabel, Object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        String name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        String fullName = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Name is undefined");
        }

        if (selectList == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Select list is empty");
        }

        Object defaultValue = GetModelStateValue(helper, fullName, typeof(String));
        if (defaultValue == null) 
        {
            defaultValue = helper.ViewData.Eval(fullName);
        }
        else
        {
            var defaultValues = new[] { defaultValue };
            IEnumerable<String> listvalues = (from value in defaultValues select value.ToString();
            var selectedValues = new HashSet<String>(listvalues, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            var newSelectList = new List<ExtendedSelectListItem>();

            foreach (ExtendedSelectListItem item in selectList)
            {
                item.Selected = (item.Value != null) ? selectedValues.Contains(item.Value) : selectedValues.Contains(item.Text);
                newSelectList.Add(item);
        }
        selectList = newSelectList;
        }

        var listItems = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (ExtendedSelectListItem item in selectList)
        {
            listItems.Append(ListItemToOption(item));
        }

        var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("select")
        {
            InnerHtml = listItems.ToString()
        };

        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", fullName, true);
        tagBuilder.GenerateId(fullName);

        ModelState state;
        if (helper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(fullName, out state))
        {
            if (state.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
               tagBuilder.AddCssClass(HtmlHelper.ValidationInputCssClassName);
            }
        }
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(helper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name));

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }


    public static String ListItemToOption(ExtendedSelectListItem item)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("option")
        {
            InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Text)
        };

        if (item.Value != null)
        {
            builder.Attributes["value"] = item.Value;
            builder.Attributes["id"] = item.Value;
        }
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            builder.Attributes["selected"] = "selected";
        }
        builder.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(item.htmlAttributes));
        return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }
}
```

Please read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx for proper usage of DropDownListFor model binding.

Comment: What would be the point of your of your `DropDownListForId()` extension? Adding an `id` attribute to an `<option>` does nothing (a `<select>` element submits the `value` attribute - the `id` is just ignored)

Comment: Right, id attribute just only available when OP wants to get option id from JS client side or sent it from ajax callback, similar to adding class attribute for `<option>` tag. The DDL itself always sending data through value attribute to binded model on postback, or option text if no value is defined.

Answer (score 1):

if your entity has a foreign key from another entity and you want show all another entity values in DropDown by razor you can first create a selectList in your action that goes to your view like:

```
var aPracticar=_modelService.getAll();   

ViewBag.Parcticar=new SelectList(aPracticar,"ID","Title");
```

and then send this selectList by viewBag to your view and in view use that like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.aPracticar,(SelectList)ViewBag.Parcticar)
```

it works and create selectList in your html with key and value that keys are Id's of aPracticar and values are what you want to show as titles of selectList.

/* edited the wrong comment and not my original post, sorry! */